# Can we give class name (custom class) for a view controller of storyboard by using code?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to reuse design of viewcontroller in next viewcontroller. I have 90% of similar code. I planned to a sub-classes of UIViewController one for parent (lets say Xvc) (which contains all common methods and properties), next two (lets say vc1 and vc2) are sub class of Xvc and are to be assigned to ViewController of storyboard as per condition.

### How can i assign custom class for ViewController vc1 or vc2 depending on condition?

or there is any solution to cope with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but there should be two viewcontroller object even in storyboard

Comment: Can you explain how can i achieve that?

Comment: Follow steps as mentioned 1) Create two UIViewController in storyboard 2)Give identifier and change custom class which you created 3)Then based on condition instantiate viewcontroller with identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The solution on top of my head is to have one viewcontroller class and prepare it to be used in both cases you have. You said it has 90% similarity, so for the 10% you may put a boolean flag as member variable to check if this is case1 or not(case2) and depending on the flag value you execute the coresponding code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a Class for a view controller from the storyboard at runtime, the storyboard is compiled so it can't be changed later.

You should consider two options

- Use the same destination view controller *(merge vc1 + vc2)* and use a flag to change its behavior, as suggested by [Ismail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35010728/1392046). You set the flag in `-prepareForSegue:sender:` from Xvc.
- Keep both vc1 and vc2, create two segues from Xvc to vc1 and from Xvc to vc2 and trigger the segue you want by calling `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` from Xvc

---

Your choice should depend on how different your view controllers are (that doesn't necessarily mean how much code is different)